# Trouble in adding the web app in new website with frame tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to add web app in my website I try with frame tag

I deploy web app as

- Execute as: User accessing the web app
- Who has access: Anyone with Google account

so it required authentication before stating the app

so I get error in website like

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

so how can I solve this problem?

**Error in website**
[image: Error in website image]

**Deploy Setting in Apps Script**
[image: deploy settings in apps script image]

---

- ***App Script Code***

  **1. code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function getEmailID() {
  return Session.getUser().getEmail();
}
```

**2. index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your Email ID is : <?= getEmailID() ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

- ***Website on other domain Code on githiub***

**1. index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project 10</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0;height: 100vh;width: 100vw;">
    <iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby4yxHaRJW_CmoTiFgOEXQ0zeD36JPwU4dwzmmMTuJmzONEOto_aItCdD6vBQ3i57Ji/exec" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**URL of Project**

**Website on other domain**

- Website on github domain = https://properson2020.github.io/project-10/
- Website Code in github = https://github.com/properson2020/project-10

**App Script**

- App script Web app = https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby4yxHaRJW_CmoTiFgOEXQ0zeD36JPwU4dwzmmMTuJmzONEOto_aItCdD6vBQ3i57Ji/exec
- Apps script code = https://script.google.com/d/1_o3_GmywWdyFRwjn6RtKdtBDujBhRtGyWW5FiWmnsELk7P-y7XhO064B/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just guessing but this is probably not allowed since accounts.google has personal information and it would be crazy for a website to display that in a frame since a website can acces pretty much all the data in the iframe

Comment: You can't frame accounts.google.com Read the linked answers. The redirect to the login page should come from the ``top`` page and not the iframed pages.

Comment: Also your apps script link is publicly accessible now, which means `Who has access:` is set to `Anyone even anonymous` and not `Anyone with Google account`

Comment: @TheMaster this project is for testing

Comment: Ok, but the project still needs a logged in user to even attempt to get email. Anonymous won't work.

Comment: yes authorization want open in iframe

Comment: @Parth Comment here or [edit] your question here or ask a new question. You can't add comments as answers to other questions. "Doesn't work" adds little to solve the problem.  Show browser console logs or other steps you've taken to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### The `getUser()` method is deprecated.

Therefore, if you want to retrieve the active user's email address you will have to use either:

- `getActiveUser()`
- `getEffectiveUser()`

It is also important to keep in mind the following:

> [`getActiveUser()`] Gets information about the current user. If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, `User.getEmail()` returns a blank string.

Therefore, as long as the web app has been authorized by the user who runs it and the user has no security policies applied, you should be able to retrieve successfully the email address using `getActiveUser()`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Session Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session).

Comment: `getActiveUser()` work fine in chrome but in other browser or in incognito mode it not working.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? I have tested this both in incognito and in another browser and it worked completely fine.

Comment: [apps script link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby4yxHaRJW_CmoTiFgOEXQ0zeD36JPwU4dwzmmMTuJmzONEOto_aItCdD6vBQ3i57Ji/exec)
open this link in incognito mode 
you get only text not an email ID
[apps script source](https://script.google.com/d/1_o3_GmywWdyFRwjn6RtKdtBDujBhRtGyWW5FiWmnsELk7P-y7XhO064B/edit?usp=sharing)